# Add upsell products more than one time

Tags: php, magento

In order to add upsell products directly to the cart, we added an "Add to Cart" button to the upsell products list.

When an upsell product is added, Magento removes it from the upsell products list. Is it possible to avoid this so that it's possible to add the upsell products multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, create a custom module that rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell`

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php

```
protected function _prepareData()
{
    ...

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        /* removing code
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
        );
        */

        $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
    }
 ...
```